# How can I try catch a val in fetch data successfully?

Tags: android, kotlin, try-catch, fetch

I am trying to fetch a JSONObject "image" that is sometimes a null value, so I set a `try {} catch {}` for my `val jsonMedia` in order to make it nullable but Im not sure if I'm missing something because it doesnt seem to work.

Whenever I comment out the `jsonMedia` my fetch works fine so I'll focus on just sharing the fetch of the "image" so the data I share doesnt get confusing.

**1st. Ill show how the "image" is in the database and what I mean by "sometimes" has a null value**
- null:

```
{
    "listCar": [
   {
    //other data
    "image": null,
    //other data
   }
 ]
}
```

- when it contains an image:

```
{
    "listCar": [
   {
    //other data
     "image": {
                "path": "Upload/UploadCarMain/UploadCarMain-200-200/30032235992008220498istanbul_adalarCar195.jpg",
                "name": "30032235992008220498istanbul_adalarCar195.jpg"
            },
    //other data
   }
 ]
}
```

Now my fetch data was followed by a course I'm watching the only difference is the values of "image" in the database Im using arent like the course which did not contain null values in their `image path`

Now here is my "Car" `class` that is supposed to get the image:

```
class Car(other data, val image: String?, other data) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Car(//other data, image='$image', //other data')"
    }
}
```

and here is my fetch code where I am trying to `try {} catch(){}` my "jsonMedia" image JSONOBject:

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): ArrayList<Car> {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground starts")

        val carList = ArrayList<Car>()
        try {
            val jsonData = JSONObject(params[0])
            val itemsArray = jsonData.getJSONArray("listCar")

            for (i in 0 until itemsArray.length()) {
                val jsonCar = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i)
                //other fetch data

                val jsonMedia: JSONObject? = try {jsonCar.getJSONObject("image")} catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {null}
                val photoURL = jsonMedia?.getString("path")

                val carObject = Car(other data, photoURL)

                carList.add(carObject)
                Log.d(TAG, ".doInBackground $carObject")
            }
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: Error processing json data. ${e.message}")
            cancel(true)
            listener.onError(e)
        }

        Log.d(TAG, ".doInBackground ends")
        return carList
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: ArrayList<Car>) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute starts")
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        listener.onDataAvailable(result)
        Log.d(TAG, ".onPostExecute ends")
    }
}
```

and here is the error I get when i run the code:

```
2020-02-14 16:42:16.483 26642-26684/com.example.wasit E/GetFlickrJsonData: doInBackground: Error processing json data. Value null at image of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way.

I had to wrap my "jsonMedia" in the following try catch:

```
val jsonMedia: JSONObject? = try {jsonCar.getJSONObject("image")} catch (e: JSONException) {
                    null
                }
```

Now my images that are null contain placeholders and the others work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the code like this. Exception class is the Parent class of all exception and provide exact cause of error.

```
for (i in 0 until itemsArray.length()) {

try {

                val jsonCar = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i)
                //other fetch data

                val jsonMedia: JSONObject? = jsonCar.getJSONObject("image")
                val photoURL = jsonMedia?.getString("path")

                val carObject = Car(other data, photoURL)

                carList.add(carObject)

} catch (ex: Exception) {
 Log.d(TAG, ex.localizedMessage.toString())
}

            }
```

Comment: This removed the error but instead of loading a list now its only loading me 1 car product

Comment: Yes.Because it give error at first iteration of loop and break the loop. please check the ex.localizedMessage.toString() for cause of error.

Comment: Same error i posted in my question "2020-02-14 17:35:44.462 28154-28227/com.example.wasit D/GetFlickrJsonData: Value null at image of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject"